# Like Counter is updating the state of every dummy post

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am beginner is React and while working on small project that replicated UI of facebook.
My dummy data is as follows:

**dummy.js**

```
export const users=[
{   'id':1,
    'username':'Jane',
    'profile_picture':'/assets/profilepictures/1.jpg',
    'desc':'This is my first post',
    'photos':'/assets/photos/a.jpg'
},
{   'id':2,
    'username':'Max',
    'profile_picture':'/assets/profilepictures/2.jpg',
    'desc':'This is my first post',
    'photos':'/assets/photos/b.jpg'
},
{
    'id':3,
    'username':'Mike',
    'profile_picture':'/assets/profilepictures/3.jpg',
    'desc':'This is my first post',
    'photos':'/assets/photos/c.jpg'
},
{
    'id':4,
    'username':'Lucas',
    'profile_picture':'/assets/profilepictures/4.jpg',
    'desc':'This is my first post',
    'photos':'/assets/photos/d.jpg'
},
{
    'id':5,
    'username':'Henry',
    'profile_picture':'/assets/profilepictures/5.jpg',
    'desc':'This is my first post',
    'photos':'/assets/photos/e.jpg'
},
{
    'id':6,
    'username':'Hopper',
    'profile_picture':'/assets/profilepictures/6.jpg',
    'desc':'This is my first post',
    'photos':'/assets/photos/f.jpg'
},
{
    'id':7,
    'username':'Dustin',
    'profile_picture':'/assets/profilepictures/7.jpg',
    'desc':'This is my first post',
    'photos':'/assets/photos/g.jpg'
},
{
    'id':8,
    'username':'Will',
    'profile_picture':'/assets/profilepictures/8.jpg',
    'desc':'This is my first post',
    'photos':'/assets/photos/h.jpg'
},
{
    'id':9,
    'username':'Erica',
    'profile_picture':'/assets/profilepictures/9.jpg',
    'desc':'This is my first post',
    'photos':'/assets/photos/i.jpg'
},
{
    'id':10,
    'username':'Suzie',
    'profile_picture':'/assets/profilepictures/10.jpg',
    'desc':'This is my first post',
    'photos':'/assets/photos/j.jpg'
},
{
    'id':11,
    'username':'Lyold',
    'profile_picture':'/assets/profilepictures/11.jpg',
    'desc':'This is my first post',
    'photos':'/assets/photos/k.jpg'
},
{
    'id':12,
    'username':'Wanda',
    'profile_picture':'/assets/profilepictures/12.jpg',
    'desc':'This is my first post',
    'photos':'/assets/photos/l.jpg'
},
{
    'id':13,
    'username':'Peter',
    'profile_picture':'/assets/profilepictures/13.jpg',
    'desc':'This is my first post',
    'photos':'/assets/photos/m.jpg'
},
{
    'id':14,
    'username':'MJ',
    'profile_picture':'/assets/profilepictures/14.jpg',
    'desc':'This is my first post',
    'photos':'/assets/photos/n.jpg'
}
```

]

and my React components that renders this data is
**Centre.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import '../styles/center.css'
import {users} from './dummy'
import {useState} from 'react'
import Button from '@mui/material/Button'
import FavoriteBorderIcon from '@mui/icons-material/FavoriteBorder';
import ChatBubbleOutlineIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ChatBubbleOutline';


export default function Centre() {

  const [likes,setLikes]=useState(0)

  const handleClick=(e)=>{
    setLikes(likes+1)
  }
  return (
    <div className='center'>
      {users.map((e)=>(          
      <div className='container' key={e.id}>
            <img src={e.profile_picture} alt="pp"  id='profile-pic'/>
            <span id='username'>{e.username}</span>
            <p id='caption'>{e.desc}</p>
            <img src={e.photos} alt="post" id='photos'/>
            <div id='btm'>            
              <FavoriteBorderIcon onClick={handleClick}/>
              <span key={e.id}>{likes} people liked this</span>
              <ChatBubbleOutlineIcon/>
             </div>
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I have implement a like counter to show the number of likes when user clicks on like button.
The problem is that when I click on like button of one specific post,the like value of all the post are getting updated.

How can I solve this  issue so that **like value of only one post** gets updated when user clicks on it.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, isn't setLikes just the function to update the likes from `useState` hook?

Comment: Yes it is, setLikes is defined in this code snippet

Comment: The issue I see is that the likes you have in the state are for all users not a specific user, I think you should handle likes based on id, not in this general manner.

Comment: Maybe you could initialize state with an array of length `users` and update the state using the index in the map function.

Comment: I tried @DSteman's code and it worked, I just had to make one minor edit mentioned in my comment on his answer.

Answer (score 2):

The number of likes is the same for each entry because you only define one number as state. You could initialize state with an array of length `users` and update the state using the index in the map function. You can see how it works by logging the state `onClick` if you're curious.

```
import React from 'react'
import '../styles/center.css'
import {users} from './dummy'
import {useState} from 'react'
import Button from '@mui/material/Button
import FavoriteBorderIcon from '@mui/icons-material/FavoriteBorder';
import ChatBubbleOutlineIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ChatBubbleOutline';


export default function Centre() {

  const initLikes = new Array(users.length).fill(0);
  const [likes,setLikes]=useState(initLikes)

  const handleClick=(index)=>{
    let tempLikes = likes
    tempLikes[index] = tempLikes[index] + 1
    setLikes(tempLikes)
  }
  return (
    <div className='center'>
      {users.map((e, index)=>(          
      <div className='container' key={e.id}>
            <img src={e.profile_picture} alt="pp"  id='profile-pic'/>
            <span id='username'>{e.username}</span>
            <p id='caption'>{e.desc}</p>
            <img src={e.photos} alt="post" id='photos'/>
            <div id='btm'>            
              <FavoriteBorderIcon onClick={() => handleClick(index)}/>
              <span key={e.id}>{likes[index]} people liked this</span>
              <ChatBubbleOutlineIcon/>
             </div>
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I tried this code and it seems working, I just had to edit `let tempLikes = likes` to `let tempLikes = likes.slice()`.

Comment: For me it works without making a shallow copy. Shouldn't we make sure to make a deep copy instead, if we would change this code?

Comment: Are you sure it worked without the shallow copy? Because I'm trying and it's not working without it, and I'm not an expert, however I think since you are giving the array to the `setLikes` function then you don't need a deep copy.

Answer (score 1):

You have likes in the Center component which is a central state for the component and you are updating it whenever any like button is pressed so it's natural to update in all the posts, what I think you need to do is add the likes count to each user in the dummy and then update the likes for that specific user when the button is pressed, I'll try to make a working example and share it if needed.

#### Edit: Adding a code example:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { users } from "./dummy";
import FavoriteBorderIcon from "@mui/icons- 
material/FavoriteBorder";
import ChatBubbleOutlineIcon from "@mui/icons- 
material/ChatBubbleOutline";

export default function App() {
  let [currentUsers, setCurrentUsers] = useState(users);

  const handleClick = (id) => {
    let user = currentUsers.find((user) => user.id === id);
    user.likes++;
    let updatedUsers = currentUsers.slice();
    setCurrentUsers(updatedUsers);
    // here I think you can write the updatedUsers to the file or DB.
  };
  return (
    <div className="center">
      {currentUsers.map((e) => (
        <div className="container" key={e.id}>
          <img src={e.profile_picture} alt="pp" id="profile-pic" />
      <span id="username">{e.username}</span>
          <p id="caption">{e.desc}</p>
          <img src={e.photos} alt="post" id="photos" />
          <div id="btm">
            <FavoriteBorderIcon onClick={() => handleClick(e.id)} />
            <span key={e.id}>{e.likes} people liked this</span>
            <ChatBubbleOutlineIcon />
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried not using the `setState` and only finding the user through id and increasing the likes, but this caused the component not to re-render so I had to use the `setState` and to use the .slice too because if the reference didn't change then the component doesn't re-render too.
Note that I edited the dummy data file and added `likes:0` to every object.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you can provide the working example.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I edited the answer with a code example, hope this helps!